# how to handle an array as a field in CGridView

Tags: yii, cgridview

I'm using CGridView but one of the field is an array ['xx' ,'yy' , 'zz',...]
How can I display that i searched for an answer but did not find

is it possible to use something like DropDownlist to display the values in the array

Comment: Why do you want to use a dropdown list, if the *value* is an array? There's nothing to select in this case. I'd rather use a string as comma separated list of array items. You can use a getter method, similar to what @frostyterrier described below.

Answer (score 0):

I have a static array `special_offer` in a model;

It will filter by the value; This is a drop down list example;

I replaced a field within the `cgridview` with a array as follows:

```
    array(
        'name' => 'special_offer',
        'value' => 'Package::$special_offer[$data->special_offer]',
        'filter' => Package::$special_offer,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use dropDownList in a CGridView column, your array needs to be associative. I recommend that you create a method in your model which converts it into an associative array, something like:

```
public function getAssociativeArray()
{
    $array = array('xx', 'yy', 'zz'); // or use an attribute value
    return array_combine(array_values($array), $array);
}
```

Then in your CGridView, add this as a column, replacing the model/field names with your own:

```
array(
    'name' => 'yourFieldName',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => 'CHtml::activeDropDownList($data, "yourFieldName", YourModel::model()->associativeArray)', 
),
```